# How to calculate$\int 1/(x^2+2)\, dx$.

Tags: integration

So, I have no idea how I'm supposed to evaluate the following integral : $\int 1/(x^2+2)\, dx$
I know that it has the form of the derivative of arctan but I'm not sure how to arrive at this result.

Thank you

Comment: try $x = \sqrt 2 \tan u$

Comment: Hint: $x^2+2=x^2+(\sqrt{2})^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\int {1 \over 1+x^2} dx = \arctan (x)$, we need to put our integral in this form. Note that:

$\int {1 \over x^2 +2}dx = \int{1 \over 2\left ( \left ({x \over \sqrt2} \right )^2 + 1 \right )}dx={1 \over 2}\int{1 \over  \left ({x \over \sqrt2} \right )^2 + 1 }dx$

Now substitue $u=x/\sqrt2$ to get:

${1 \over 2}\int \sqrt2 {1 \over u^2 +1}du={1 \over \sqrt2} \int {1 \over u^2 +1}du={1 \over \sqrt 2} \arctan(u)={ 1 \over \sqrt2} \arctan(x/\sqrt2)$